# FreeBSD Installation

Tags: freebsd, system-installation

I have followed all the installation steps, installation is done but when I reboot it's not loading the host that I have created `FreeBSD.local`. It's loading by default root host.
[image]

Comment: Configure the host name then?

Comment: The `hostname` is a setting in your `/etc/rc.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration of the hostname is done by changing `/etc/rc.conf.local`.  A description of this file and an example of it that actually sets the name of the host is found in in section [12.4.1. Managing System-Specific Configuration](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/config/#configtuning-core-configuration) of [the FreeBSD Handbook](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/):

> ```
> hostname="node1.example.org"
> ```

See also the [`rc.conf(5)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.conf&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+13.0-RELEASE+and+Ports) manual on FreeBSD which further explains the `/etc/rc.conf.local` file and the `hostname` variable therein.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the time-honored method of editing `/etc/rc.conf` or `/etc/rc.conf.local`, recent versions of FreeBSD offer the `sysrc` utility to streamline workflows that require tweaks to the `rc.conf` subsystem.

For example, if the hostname you want to use is `FreeBSD.local` then as `root`, the command:

```
sysrc hostname=FreeBSD.local
```

will do that.  That hostname will be set upon the next reboot.

If you would like the `hostname` setting to take effect immediately, then you should additionally issue the following command, again as `root`:

```
hostname FreeBSD.local
```